# Map over values of one column

Tags: f#, deedle

I want to map over the values of the `Title` column of my dataframe.
The solution I came up with is the following:

```
df.Columns.[ [ "Title"; "Amount" ] ]
|> Frame.mapCols(fun k s -> 
    if k = "Title" 
    then s |> Series.mapValues (string >> someModif >> box) 
    else s.Observations |> Series)
```

Since `s` is of type `ObjectSeries<_>` I have to cast it to `string`, modify it then `box` it back.

Is there a recommended way to map over the values of a single column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GetColumn:

```
df.GetColumn<string>("Title")
|> Series.mapValues(someModif)
```

Or in more F#-style:

```
df
|> Frame.getCol "Title"
|> Series.mapValues(string >> someModif)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to add a `TitleMapped` column with:

```
df?TitleMapped <- df?Title |> Series.mapValues (...your mapping fn...)
```

...and then throw away the `Title` column with `df |> Frame.dropCol "Title"` (or not bother if you don't care whether it stays or not).

Or, if you don't like the "imperativeness" of `<-`, you can do something like:

```
df?Title 
|> Series.mapValues (...your mapping fn...)
|> fun x -> Frame( ["Title"], [x] ) 
|> Frame.join JoinKind.Left (df |> Frame.dropCol "Title")
```

Comment: A good option. Although this operator does not always work as expected.

Comment: For example, this code: http://pastebin.com/0kjKmXwz  gives me an exception. Although I can't understand why.

Comment: Gah! This is annoying... Well, it appears the `?` infix operator only works for numerical-value columns. To make a string column work, using your example from pastebin (changed a bit to shorten, but crucial is the one with `.["Title"]`):

`type nPerson =  { Title:string; Amount:decimal }
let npeopleRecds = 
    [ {  Title = "some";  Amount = 51M   }
      {  Title = "some1"; Amount = 28.9M }
      {  Title = "some3"; Amount = 20M;  } ]
(Frame.ofRecords npeopleRecds |> Frame.cols ).["Title"]
|> Series.mapValues(string >> (fun s -> s.ToUpper()))
|> fun series -> series.Format() 
|> printfn "%A"`

Comment: OK, all editing attempts of the above comment were in vain. Point I was trying the make is that for string-containing columns like `Title` we need to use `(df |> Frame.cols ).["Title"]`, or basically, your original answer. I live and learn.

Comment: Thanks @mt99. Adding a column is what I ended up doing. Instead of using the `?` operator which is meant for `float` types, I used `frame.AddColumn("Label", frame |> Frame.getCol "Title" |> Series.mapValues someModif) `

Comment: @ Kimserey, The "?" operator adds not only numeric data. So `df?Label <- ...` will work well with any types.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you may want to map over values of a specific column and keep that mapped column in the frame. Supposing we have a frame called someFrame with 2 columns (Col1 and Col2) and we want to transform Col1 (for example, Col1 + Col2), what I usually do is:

```
someFrame
|> Frame.replaceCol "Col1"
    (Frame.mapRowValues (fun row ->
        row.GetAs<float>("Col1") + row.GetAs<float>("Col2"))
    someFrame)
```

If you want to create a new column instead of replacing it, all you have to do is to change the "replaceCol" method for "addCol" and choose a new name for the column instead of "Col1" of the given example. I don't know if this is the most efficient way, but it worked for me so far.